# Can not deserialize instance of test.MyPojo out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I am not able to convert my **JSON** to **POJO** objects.

My **JSON** output is:

```
[ {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "latha"
}, {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "kala"
}]
```

My POJO is:

```
public class NSCLockData {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

My class is:

```
public void insert(org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> msg) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        MyPojo data=mapper.readValue(msg.getPayload().toString(), MyPojo.class);
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(data);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you have array of objects..

Comment: What @MarounMaroun says is true, you can't create an instance of a POJO from a json array. Also you're trying to create an instance of MyPojo but your class is called NSCLockData

Comment: Sorry, my pojo class is MyPojo.class. After trying this also have this error. how can i rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Create your new POJO so that it should be array of NSLoackData

```
public class ArrayofNS implements Serialaizable(){

 // create serialisation

private List<NSLoackData> arrayof;

// getter and setteers
}
```

In Your main code where you need to convert the incoming json to your POJO class write something like below

consider u have the above JSON (Array ) in a JSONObject called result;

```
JSONArray js = new JSOANArray();
```

convert your above json into JSONArray with the above line of code

```
js = result;
```

iterate through the loop and get the value

```
List<NSLockData> lk = new ArrayList<NSLockData>();
NSLockData data;
for(I=0;i<=js.length();I++){
data = new NSLockDate();
data = new ObjectMapper.readValue(js.get(i).toString(),NSLOckData.class);
lk.add(data);
}
```

Comment: i used simply different

Comment: Message object = mapper.readValue(message.getPayload().toString(), Message.class);
  List<MyPojo> lst = object .getData();
  ListIterator<MyPojo> litr = lst.listIterator();
  while(litr.hasNext())
  {
   MyPojo obj = litr.next();  
   
  }